# Gradle subproject transition of dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, java-17

I have a 2 module Gradle project, structure as below:

[image]

In my *DemoApplication* I would like to use class *CircularFifoQueue* which is in *org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4* dependency declared in *library* project. However, I cannot do that (*error: cannot find symbol CircularFifoQueue...*) , even that *MyService* is visible in my *DemoApplication* class.
It seems that in Gradle 7 dependencies are not transisioned from subprojects, but I couldn't find that info in gradle docks.
I'm using java 17 temurin and Gradle 7.4.

Here are sources:

DemoApplication:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.example.multimodule")
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

    private final MyService myService;

    public DemoApplication(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        CircularFifoQueue<String> result = new CircularFifoQueue<>();
        return myService.message();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Application build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':library')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Application serttings.gradle:

```
includeFlat 'library'
rootProject.name = 'application'
```

Library build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.1' apply false
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue when the library is built with Java17. It was working fine when using Java8. Did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can add compileOnly statements to the build.gradle of the subproject that reference the cascaded dependency, this fixed this issue for me, eg:

```
compileOnly('org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4')
```